# Easiest way to add landscape Orientation And code in android

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, orientation, landscape

I am new in `android` and want to know how to add `landscape` mode in `android` can anyone tell me about the easiest way to do that. I'm looking for a way that is very simple.

If you have this kind of question check the answer below.

thanks....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a simplest way to add a `landscape` mode (add `landscape folder`, `landscape xml file` and code) in `android studio`. You just have to click one or two times to do that.
when you are in `xml` file opened look at the right there is a `preview panel` that show your device click the [image] button and click on `switch to layout-land`. It Automatically adds `layout_land.xml` file into your file structure AND also opens it in code & preview.
Check the image below...

[image]

Comment: If you have the answer, why are you asking for help?? Your question needs clarification.

Comment: I ask this to share my knowledge.