# How to create landscape layout in Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android, layout, landscape

I'm beginner in Android programming.
In previous versions Android Studio landscape layout create simple way with creation new layout (see picture)

[image: img1]

How I may create layout for landscape orientation in new version Android Studio.

Comment: you don't really need the ide for this. Every layout inside `layout-land` will be loaded only when your phone is in landscape mode. If you don't have it under `res/` you can create it manually

Comment: Create manually directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rightclick on your layout folder > new layout-ressource file.
The option is called Orientation in the same dialog. Right above UI Mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simplest way to add a `landscape` Orientation with `landscape folder` , `landscape xml file` and code in simple 2 clicks Take a look at [This Example Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665181/easiest-way-to-add-landscape-code-in-android/32665182#32665182) Hope it will help you.